# How do I prevent duplicate items in the cart?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

For the current structure of database:

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy1qw.jpg)

Users

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 60)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_product",
            joinColumns ={@JoinColumn (name = "users_username",  referencedColumnName = "username")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "Products_idProducts", referencedColumnName = "idProducts")}
    )
    List<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<Products>();
```

Products

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Products implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idProducts")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private String price;

    @Column(name = "image")
    private byte [] image;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productsList")
    List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();

//setters - getters
```

I want to implement a shopping basket.

**What I have now:** A page with products and checkboxes on the view page.  I find these products and send them to my controller, and afterwards set them to the current user.

```
productsList = myService.findManyProducts(toAdd);
            user.setProductsList(productsList);
            myService.updateUser(user);


@Transactional
public void updateUser(User user){
    userDao.update(user);
}
```

update user function:

```
@Override
public void update(User user) {
    entityManager.merge(user);
}
```

These actions are entered in the database as different values, depending on the latest additions.

**What I want:** 
User adds some products to cart, browse other items, and add new products to the cart. How do I ensure that duplicate items are not found in the cart?  Does JPA have some standard methods? Or do I need to check the product list by myself before adding them to the database?

Comment: You read up on Java collection types, since a List can contain duplicates and a Set cannot. Nothing to do with JPA

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the `List` collection to a `Set` in the `User` entity.